# What is a correct code that I should write, in the MetaTrader4 Terminal Expert Advisor?

Tags: mql4, metatrader4

I would like to know the correct code, that I should write, in the Expert Advisor, MetaTrader4 Terminal, so as to import a value, from an Excel book, with a name **`xfox`**, Sheet **`casa9`**, the value that is in a cell **`A3`**.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! We're here to help with code debugging, not writing your code. Please read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

### As-Is state:

There is no direct way, how a MetaTrader4 Terminal `MQL4` language code-execution unit would read a cell from Excel **`xfox.xls`** file.

### To-Be state:

Nevertheless, there are ways how to integrate such functionality, by using an externally implemented **`DLL`**-function or by using a distributed-computing approach and ask for such a value an externally operated ( distributed-)-agent, that can { directly- | indirectly-}-interact with **`xfox.xls`** file.

So the task is doable in several ways.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your excel version.

if it is MS 2003  - you can download the pachage [here](http://www.fx1.net/excellink.php), if you have 2007 and newer - you can have a paid version of XLSgate or some other products, [XLS](http://xlsgate.com/) has a free package also but it is limited so probably you will have to install 2003 if that works for you.

the free version has all necessary functions, all you need is to

```
#import
   int ExcelPutString(int,int,int,string);
   int ExcelPutValue(int,int,int,double);
   double ExcelGetValue(int,int,int);
   string ExcelGetString(int,int,int);
#import
```

about specific sheet - do not remember, seems need to check each sheet name and to know their names and order and input that manually